# Cannot set default App Identity Service Account on Google App Engine for local development

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase

Following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine#securedata

I've got it working except that when I authenticate the custom token with Firebase, I get the following error:

```
Error: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.
```

I have isolated the problem to the App Identity token signing. This is because the code works fine deployed to app-engine. It's just an issue when I try on devserver/localhost.

I have following the AppEngine documentation about setting up the default Service Account locally.

1. Setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of the .json service account keys. I've triple checked the variable is being set.
2. I tried the alternative method using the gcloud sdk, logging in as my *owner* account: `gcloud beta auth application-default login`. Still no luck.

To check I actually changed account, I use this method to get: `AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getServiceAccountName();`. In both configurations I detailed about, this method returns `appname@localhost`. I was expecting this to be the service account ID given in the .json. ie `appname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

So I'm a bit at a loss how to debug this problem further, I assume the check I'm doing above is actually proving the validity of the configured service account. Perhaps its something unique to my setup?

- Using App Engine Java, latest SDK 1.9.54
- Run configuration launched with Maven 3 + IntelliJ
- ArchLinux environment